# ng-show not working on window scroll

Tags: html, angularjs, scroll, ng-show

I am supposed to display an element on top of the html doc. If the user scrolls and the element goes out of the view, i am supposed display the same element with different style at bottom of the page. I have implemented a simple scroll functinality and put ng-show on the bottom element to fire as soon as top element goes out of view.

```
var tester = document.getElementsByClassName('recommendationTable')[0];

window.onscroll = function() {
vm.itemShow = checkVisible(tester);
// $scope.apply();
console.log(checkVisible(tester));
};

function checkVisible(elm) {
var rect = elm.getBoundingClientRect();
var viewHeight = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight);
return !(rect.bottom < 0 || rect.top - viewHeight >= 0);
}
```

Here is the HTML Code (first and second element respectively):

```
<table  class="pull-right col-sm-9 recommendationTable"></table>

<table  class="pull-right col-sm-12 recommendationTableBottom" ng-show='!
{{vm.itemShow}}'></table>
```

Even though vm.itemShow eventually displays 'false' in console when the first element goes out of view, it does not trigger the ng-show in the second element. When i resize the window, the ng-show is triggered even though ng-show value remains the same (false). How do i trigger ng-show whenever vm.itemShow turns from true to false?

Answer (score 0):

Try by changing as follows,

```
<table  class="pull-right col-sm-12 recommendationTableBottom" ng-show="vm.itemShow"></table>
```

OR

you can use $timeout() func within onscroll event (within timeout function change your scope variable value), (bcoz $timeout will handle digest cycle)

Comment: i have tried both but it doesnt work. Do you have any other suggestions?